# ¿Que método y de que manera debo utilizar? Arrays JS

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy trabado con un ejercicio que parece ser bastante simple. A ver si alguno puede darme una mano.

````
var families = [];
module.exports = {
 reset: function () {
   // No es necesario modificar esta función (Ya está completa)
   characters = [];
   families = [];
 },

 listCharacter: function (family, pluckName) {
   // Devuelve un arreglo con todos los personajes
   // Si recibe un nombre de familia como parámetro debería filtrar solo los personajes de ella
   // Si recibe un segundo parámetro en true debe devolver únicamente los nombres de los personajes
    }```
````

Comment: ¿Necesitas la implementación completa de `listCharacter`?

Comment: Hola, si es necesario.